# prev() gives value undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm updating a cart value, in which I want to increment or decrement the value of a cart item, however I am not getting the `qty` value but undefined. I am using `next` and `prev` method of jQuery to get the result.

javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    var cart_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var qty = $(this).siblings('input[name="qty"]').val();

    alert(qty);

    e.preventDefault()
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('/increment') }}",
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        qty: qty,
        id: cart_id,
        product_id: product_id
      },
      success: function(result) {
        jQuery('#qty').val(result.qty);
        jQuery('#subtotal').val(result.subtotal);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Quantity">
      <div class="plus-minus" style="width:150px; ">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyminus" id="subs" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
              <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="form-control input-number" value="{{$v_contents->qty}}">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyplus" data-type="plus" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
              <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var t = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
function total(){
t=0;
$("input[name='subtotal']").each(function (){
t = t + this.value;
});
$("td.hidden-xs.text-center strong").html(`Total: ${t}`);
}
  $(".qtyplus,.qtyminus").click(function (){
    var input = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name^='qty']"); $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find("input[name='subtotal']").val($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("td[data-th^='Price']").text()*input.val());
total();
});
  $('span button').click(function(e) {
    var cart_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var qty = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name^='qty']").val();
    var input = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name^='qty']");

    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name^='qty']").val(($(this).hasClass("qtyminus")) ? --qty : ++qty);
    e.preventDefault()
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('/increment') }}",
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        qty: qty,
        id: cart_id,
        product_id: product_id
      },
      success: function(result) {
        input.val(result.qty);
        jQuery('#subtotal').val(result.subtotal);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($getResult as $v_contents)
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td data-th="Product">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs"><img src="{{asset('images/'.$v_contents->image)}}" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/ height="100" width="100"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <h4 class="nomargin">{{$v_contents->name_of_subcategory}}</h4>
         <p>{{$v_contents->description_of_product}}</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td data-th="Price">12</td>
      <td data-th="Quantity">
       <div class="plus-minus" style="width:150px; ">
        <div class="input-group">
         
                 
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyminus" id="subs" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
                         <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
                     </button>
                
                     <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="form-control qty" value="{{$v_contents->qty}}" >
                      
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyplus" data-type="plus" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
                         <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                     </button>
                 
             
           </div>
       </div>        
      </td>
      <?php  $subtotal=$v_contents->price*$v_contents->qty; ?>
      <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">
       <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" class="form-control input-number" value="<?php echo $subtotal; ?>" min="1" max="10"></td>
      <td class="actions" data-th="">
       <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{ url('/delete-to-cart'.$v_contents->cart_id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>        
      </td>
     </tr>
    
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
     @endforeach
     <!-- <tr class="visible-xs">
      <td class="text-center"><strong>Total 1.99</strong></td>
     </tr> -->
     <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
      <td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total </strong></td>
      <td><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart?mfid=1546373779156_cb91e3a2b2dc7&flowlogging_id=cb91e3a2b2dc7#/checkout/shoppingCart" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Checkout <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></td>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>
   </table>
```

Comment: Hello now i am getting correct value of qty but when i am adding multiple items in cart and perform increment operation it only increment qty of first item of cart. I think need changes in success here id of qty will be overwrites

Comment: are you getting my confusion?

Comment: it return false value. I want qty in ajax success. It is correct for first cart item but it can not work for next value due to id of qty will repeat

Comment: Sorry, i did not seen your success function. And where is your `#subtotal`?

Comment: hello ignore #subtotal now and wants only qty plz solve issue its very urgent

Comment: sir again one issue occur plz refer my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766907/wishlist-heart-icon-color-change-based-on-selection-in-laravel-5-7

Comment: If this helped you then don't forget to accept and upvote answer 

Comment: hello sir i am changing my blade file now i want subtotal and total. how  can i obtained subtotal and then total

Comment: You should probably open new question for that but check my answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

`input[name="qty"]` isn't a sibling of the `.qtyplus` element you assigned the event handler to. You need to traverse the DOM to the parent of the button, as that is the element which is the sibling:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    var cart_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var qty = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name="qty"]').val();
    
    console.log(qty);
    
    // the rest of your AJAX code...
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Quantity">
      <div class="plus-minus" style="width:150px; ">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyminus" id="subs" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
              <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="form-control input-number" value="{{$v_contents->qty}}">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyplus" data-type="plus" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
              <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello now i am getting correct value of qty but when i am adding multiple items in cart and perform increment operation it only increment qty of first item of cart. I think need changes in success here id of qty will be overwrites

Comment: Are the elements added to the DOM dynamically after the page loads? If so you need to use a delegated event handler

Answer (score 0):

`input[name="qty"]` is not direct sibling of `.qtyplus` button. 
You need to use `$(this).parent().siblings('input[name="qty"]').val()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    var cart_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var product_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    var qty = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name="qty"]').val();

    alert(qty);

    e.preventDefault()
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('/increment') }}",
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        qty: qty,
        id: cart_id,
        product_id: product_id
      },
      success: function(result) {
        jQuery('#qty').val(result.qty);
        jQuery('#subtotal').val(result.subtotal);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-th="Quantity">
      <div class="plus-minus" style="width:150px; ">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyminus" id="subs" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
              <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
          <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="form-control input-number" value="{{$v_contents->qty}}">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number qtyplus" data-type="plus" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
              <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello now i am getting correct value of qty but when i am adding multiple items in cart and perform increment operation it only increment qty of first item of cart. I think need changes in success here id of qty will be overwrites