# Wishlist heart icon color change based on selection in laravel 5.7

Tags: ajax, laravel

my requirement of coding is "when i am click on wishlist heart icon. if i am not login, then i am going to login page &  If i am login then fa-fa heart color is change orange when i am added item in wishlist & grey when it remove. i am sending json response refer my coding.

controller:

```
public function add_to_wishlist(Request $req)
    {
         $userId=Session::get('userid');
         if(empty($userId))
         {
            return response()->json(['status'=> 1]);
         }
        else
         {
            $checkWishlist=DB::select('select * from wishlist where user_id=? && product_id=?',[$userId,$req->sub_id]);
             if($checkWishlist)
             {
               DB::table('wishlist')->where('user_id',$userId)->where('product_id',$req->sub_id)->delete();
               return response()->json(['status'=> 2]);              
             }
             else
             {
              DB::table('wishlist')->insert(['user_id'=>$userId,'product_id'=>$req->sub_id]);
              return response()->json(['status'=> 3]);
             }
         }
    }
```

blade code:

```
 <input type="text"  name="status" id="status" class="form-control status" value="">
                    <a class="sub" data-id="{{$value->sub_id}}" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="float:right;color:grey"></i></a>
```

jquery and ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sub').click(function(e) { 

    var sub_id=$(this).attr('data-id');
    var input=$(this).prev();
    e.preventDefault()
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
         jQuery.ajax({

                  url: "{{ url('/add-to-wishlist') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     sub_id: sub_id,
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                     input.val(result.status);

                  }});

  });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: what is the reponse you are getting

Answer (score 1):

First add `dataType:'JSON'`

Then add some conditions in `success` function:

```
$('.sub').click(function(e) {
var input = $(this);
...
...
$.ajax({
...
success: function(result){
    var status = result.status;
    input.val(status);
    if(status==1){
    //Not logged in
    window.location.href ="path/to/login";
    }else if(status==2){
    //Delete
    input.next().css('background','gray');
    }else{
    //Logged in
    input.next().css('background','orange');
    }
}});
});
});
```